# how to add classname to all elements starting with specific id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Before you lash out on me, I know this question might be a possible duplicate.
I tried every other post I found on stackoverflow and failed.

I want to add a class name to all elements in my html which start with 'subclass', followed by a single digit number(classid), followed by a random number. I dont exactly know how many elements are there as it is being generated dynamically with servlets.

Following is the code I tried to run:

```
<style>
.bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
<script>
function highlight(classid){
    alert(classid);
    $("p[id^='subclass'+classid]").addClass('bold');
    alert('hello world');
}
</script>
<p id='subclass25'>Hello World </p>
```

I get the alert for classid but not the alert for 'hello world'. So I know for sure my JQuery is wrong....

Comment: Your quotes are mismatched where you're trying to concatenate `classid`. I'd suggest using an editor with syntax highlighting as it makes it almost impossible to make errors like this.

Comment: Correct the Quote, your quotes near the variable "classid" is not correct, because of incorrect text it is treating it like a string.
        $("p[id^='subclass" + classid + "']").addClass('bold');
Try above code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have missed the quotes which is the reason jquery selector is not getting created properly, see below

```js
 highlight('25');
 function highlight(classid){
        alert(classid);
        $("p[id^='subclass" + classid + "']").addClass('bold');
        alert('hello world');
    }
```

```css
.bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id='subclass25'>Hello World </p>
```